# jQuery hide element by class doesn't hide all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got a problem. When I'm hiding all elements with specific class only elements **except** the clicked one are hidden. I have no idea why this is happening.

if I put the popup somewhere else on the page, it's working. I think it has to be related to the css, but I couldn't figure out which property is causing this problem.

Code

```js
      $('.scroll-nav-item').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
      });
      $('.close-popup').click(function() {
          $('.popup').hide();
      });
```

```css
:root{
  --nav-height: 5rem;
  --one-page-minus-nav-height: calc(100vh - var(--nav-height));
  --scroll-nav-width: 80px;
  --bg-light: #f8f9fa;
  --bg-dark: #343a40;
  --bg-dark-hover: #606b76;
}

#scroll_nav{
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(var(--nav-height) + 10rem);
  width: var(--scroll-nav-width);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.scroll-nav-item{
  display: flex;
  overflow: visible;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--bg-light);
  --offset: 5px;
  width: calc(var(--scroll-nav-width) - calc(var(--offset) / 2));
  height: calc(var(--scroll-nav-width) - var(--offset));
  margin: calc(var(--offset) / 2) calc(var(--offset) / 2) calc(var(--offset) / 2) 0;
  border: 2px solid var(--bg-light);
  background-color: var(--bg-dark);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup{
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--scroll-nav-width);
  cursor: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.close-popup{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scroll-nav-item:hover{
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-hover);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: #A3A3A3">
<!-- Scroll Navigation -->
  <div id="scroll_nav" class="d-none d-lg-block rounded-right" style="">
    <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
          open Popup
          <div class="popup" style="display: none; min-width: 600px">
            Popin around
          <span class="close-popup"><b>close</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
      open popup
      <div id="pu1" class="popup" style="display:none; min-width: 600px">
        popin around
        <span class="close-popup"><b>close</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
```

As you can see, if you open both popups and try to close one of them, only the other popup gets hidden.

Can you help me understanding what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

When you click `close`, the handler gets executed, hiding all elements that match your selector.

After the handler  has finished, the event [bubbles up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) the DOM, reaching the `.nav-item` parent and triggering its handler, since it's a `click` event after all, resulting in the child popup showing again.

To solve this, you have to [`stop` the event from bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```
$('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.popup').hide();
});
```

This will hide all open popups. If you want to close only the popup that's clicked, you have to modify the close handler so it's restricted that element, akin to what you do with the open handler and `.find()`, by using [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) functions.

```
$('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('.popup').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add `stopPropagation()` to the `click()` event of the `.close-popup` element:

```js
$('.scroll-nav-item').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.popup').show();
});
$('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".popup").hide();
});
```

```css
:root{
  --nav-height: 5rem;
  --one-page-minus-nav-height: calc(100vh - var(--nav-height));
  --scroll-nav-width: 80px;
  --bg-light: #f8f9fa;
  --bg-dark: #343a40;
  --bg-dark-hover: #606b76;
}

#scroll_nav{
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(var(--nav-height) + 10rem);
  width: var(--scroll-nav-width);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.scroll-nav-item{
  display: flex;
  overflow: visible;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--bg-light);
  --offset: 5px;
  width: calc(var(--scroll-nav-width) - calc(var(--offset) / 2));
  height: calc(var(--scroll-nav-width) - var(--offset));
  margin: calc(var(--offset) / 2) calc(var(--offset) / 2) calc(var(--offset) / 2) 0;
  border: 2px solid var(--bg-light);
  background-color: var(--bg-dark);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup{
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--scroll-nav-width);
  cursor: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.close-popup{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scroll-nav-item:hover{
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-hover);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll_nav" class="d-none d-lg-block rounded-right" style="">
  <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
    open Popup
    <div class="popup" style="display: none; min-width: 600px">
      Popin around
      <span class="close-popup"><b>close</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-nav-item rounded">
    open popup
    <div id="pu1" class="popup" style="display:none; min-width: 600px">
      popin around
      <span class="close-popup"><b>close</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you only want to close the popup in which the `.close-popup` was clicked, adjust this to

```
 $('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('.popup').hide();
 });
```

Comment: This removes both of them. Not sure if OP wants this.

Comment: @ikiK I've added it to my answer in case it's wanted.